# How to append a string to the title property of a link with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get all external links with a specific CSS class (`.knk_aff_link`) and append a string to their title property.

I have this jQuery snippet already:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('a').filter(function () {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname && $(this).hasClass('knk_aff_link');
  }).prop('title', $(this).attr('title') + ' | Affiliate Link');
});
```

This script filters correctly all external links with the specific CSS class but `$(this).attr('title')` delivers the title of the current page, not the title of the link.

Original link:

```
<a href="https://external-example-link.org" class="knk_aff_link" title="This title is already set">Link</a>
```

Link should be like this with the jQuery function:

```
<a href="https://external-example-link.org" class="knk_aff_link" title="This title is already set | Affiliate Link">Link</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to add `Affiliate Link` exact text  to the title part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the `this` refers to the window. I used `each` to get a refernce for each of the `a` elements.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname && $(this).hasClass('knk_aff_link');
  }).each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).prop('title', $(elem).attr('title') + ' | Affiliate Link');

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://external-example-link.org" class="knk_aff_link" title="This title is already set">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. I only added a line to check if the title is empty or not.